# symfony2 console arguments

Tags: symfony, console, command-line-arguments

I want to create a single **named** argument/option for symfony command. And want symfony to distinguish those 3 options:

- `my:command`, which means something like `my:command --arg=null`
- `my:command --arg`, which means `my:command --arg=defalutValue`
- `my:command --arg=someValue`, which is fully explicit.

I.e. I want two working modes for code under that command: default one and non-default with additional argument, and that arg should have default value.

I understand, that I could create 2 args, but I'm looking for one-arg-to-rule-them-all solution.

Is it possible to accomplish that with built-in classes or should I create custom ones? If solution is only available with custom classes, please tell me, where to start (i.e. "create subclass of ..." or "install a bundle named ..."), cause I'm not familiar with Symfony2's architecture.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is possible:

```
->addOption('arg', 'a', InputOption::VALUE_NONE)
```

- my:command => `$input->getOption('arg') //false`
- my:command --arg => `$input->getOption('arg') //true`
- my:command --arg=5 => `$input->getOption('arg') //5`

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, it's the first time I use this method, but I think that in order to obtain this result you have to use InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL as a third argument.

Comment: Indeed with the InputOption::VALUE_NONE you get a runtime exception : The option does not accept a value.

Comment: With `InputOption::VALUE_NONE` we get an exception if the options gets a value

Answer (score 1):

Answer by corvax is incorrect and doesn't work. As of today, you just cannot achieve this.

It is even stated in the Console documentation: [Using Command Options](http://symfony.com/doc/current/console/input.html#using-command-options).

See also these issues on GitHub:

- [#8135 [Console] Input options with InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL and InputOption::VALUE_NONE not working as expected](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/8135)
- [#11883 [Console] Added three state long option](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/11883)
- [#12769 [Console] Ability to use option default only if the option was passed](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/12769)
- [#12773 [Console] Add method to know parsed option](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/12773)

Answer (score -3):

Symfony2 have console component which can be used separately. You can see documentation [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console.html). For more example you can check [implementations](https://github.com/sensio/SensioGeneratorBundle/tree/master/Command) of SensioGeneratorBundle.

Comment: I already read the documentation and found no way to create this tree-way option/argument. And I don't need to use this component separately. I need a way this could be solved or approvement, this couldn't be solved.